# compare two arrays depending on keys php

Tags: php

I have two arrays and i want to extract only the values from the second array only if its key matches the first array key.

My first array is

```
 [deal_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 75
                [5] => 76
                [10] => 77
                [15] => 79
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 84
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 86
                [3] => 88
                [8] => 89
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 97
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => 100
                [4] => 104
            )

    )
```

My second array is

```
 [package_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 10
                [1] => 75
                [2] => 75
                [3] => 75
                [4] => 75
                [5] => 67
                [6] => 34
                [7] => 89
                [10] => 04
                [15] => 75
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 10
                [1] => 29
                [2] => 34
                [3] => 45
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 12
                [3] => 23
                [4] => 45
                [5] => 76
                [6] => 87
                [8] => 45
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 34
                [1] => 54
                [2] => 34

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => 145
                [1] => 143
                [6] => 146
                [4] => 344
            )

    )
```

Expected output:

```
[package_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10
                    [5] => 67
                    [10] => 04
                    [15] => 75
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [3] => 23
                    [8] => 45
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 34

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 145
                    [4] => 344

                )

        )
```

I want only those values from the second array whose key matches the first array. I want my second array to look exactly like my first except the values.

Thanks

Comment: So what would be the expected output in your example?

Comment: you can take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php

Answer (score 0):

I think that is best done with some for loops. Will not be that efficient, but as far as I know there is no real automated way of doing this.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but it may be a start. So don't just copy past the code (because it will probably not work because it isn't tested), but maybe it is a good start for your own code.

```
for($arr1 as $key11 => $val11){
    if(isset($arr2[$key11])){
        $contains = false;
        for($val11 as $key12 => $val12){
            if(isset($arr2[$key11][$key12]){
                // Contains
                $contains = true;
            }
        }
        if(!$contains){
            // Doesn't contain
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to replicate your array into this:

```
$deal = array(
    array(
        0=>75, 5=>76, 10=>77, 15=>79,
    ),
    array(
        0=>84,
    ),
    array(
        0=>86, 3=>88, 8=>89,
    ),
);

$package = array(
    array(
        0=>10, 1=>75, 2=>75, 3=>75, 4=>75, 5=>67, 6=>34, 7=>89, 10=>04, 15=>75,
    ),
    array(
        0=>10, 1=>29, 2=>34, 3=>45,
    ),
    array(
        0=>12, 3=>23, 4=>45, 5=>76, 6=>87, 8=>45,
    ),
);
```

and process it using this snippet:

```
$result = array();

foreach($deal as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
        if(array_key_exists($key2, $package[$key])){
            if(!isset($key, $result)){
                $result[$key] = array();
            }
            $result[$key][$key2] = $package[$key][$key2];
        }
    }
}
```

> **NOTE:** The real trick here is, by using array_key_exists() to check if the key in question exists in `$package` array.

With the following results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [5] => 67
            [10] => 4
            [15] => 75
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [3] => 23
            [8] => 45
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. Taking clues from the suggestion above. I finally got the answer.

here is the working code:

```
 foreach ($deal_ids as $dealkey => $dealval) {
            foreach ($dealval as $dkey => $dval) {
                foreach ($deal_duration as $dukey => $duval) {
                    foreach ($duval as $deukey => $deuval) {

                        if ($dkey == $deukey) {
                            $dur[$dealkey][$deukey] = $deuval;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) by looping into an array that is small.